# How to get authenticated user in spring-security-oauth

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, spring-security

For my REST aplication I used Basic Authentication (sending user's password and login with every request). For some needs I obtain logged user using:

```
User loggedUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

But then I implemented Spring-Security-Oauth2 and I am using access token instead password and login. And now .getPrincipal() method returns "anonymousUser".
So my question: Is there any way to obtain logged User somehow as above in spring-security-oauth?

**EDIT:**
I figured out that I had a proplem in my security "intercept-url pattern". So now I can use SecurityContextHolder from which I can obtain authenticated user.

Answer (score 2):

inside controller method you can add this paramter then it will be injected for you and you can access user information

```
getUserAuthentication(OAuth2Authentication auth,Model model)
```